# Trouble with linking in Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

If I try and compile the makefile in this plea for help, the terminal gives me the following for all my object files:

```
linker input file unused because linking not done
```

, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to compile it so that I can create the executable.
What I've tried is:

Removing -c, so it looks like

```
$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

, which gives me a boatload of cygwin errors, so that's not the solution AFAIK.
Here's a list of the errors, without all the duplicates:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `Vector3D::Vector3D()'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x32): multiple definition of `Vector3D::Vector3D(float, float, float)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x32): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x76): multiple definition of `Vector3D::getX() const'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x76): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x88): multiple definition of `Vector3D::getY() const'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x88): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x9c): multiple definition of `Vector3D::getZ() const'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x9c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0xb0): multiple definition of `Vector3D::operator*(Vector3D) const'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xb0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x106): multiple definition of `Vector3D::operator%(Vector3D) const'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x106): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x1d4): multiple definition of `Vector3D::operator+(Vector3D) const'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1d4): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x256): multiple definition of `Vector3D::operator-(Vector3D) const'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x256): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x2d8): multiple definition of `Vector3D::operator*(float) const'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2d8): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x344): multiple definition of `Vector3D::operator/(float) const'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x344): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x3b0): multiple definition of `Vector3D::Magnitude()'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3b0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x418): multiple definition of `Vector3D::Normal()'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x418): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x59c): multiple definition of `Vector3D::Matrixed()'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x59c): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x5ea): multiple definition of `Vector3D::~Vector3D()'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5ea): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x5f6): multiple definition of `Matrix3D::Matrix3D()'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x5f6): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x666): multiple definition of `Matrix3D::Matrix3D(Vector3D, Vector3D, Vector3D)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x666): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x6ec): multiple definition of `Matrix3D::Matrix3D(float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x6ec): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x768): multiple definition of `Matrix3D::operator*(Matrix3D)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x768): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x876): multiple definition of `Matrix3D::rotateX(float)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x876): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x920): multiple definition of `Matrix3D::rotateY(float)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x920): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0x9d0): multiple definition of `Matrix3D::rotateZ(float)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x9d0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0xa7c): multiple definition of `operator*(Vector3D const&, Matrix3D const&)'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa7c): first defined here   
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.text+0xbea): multiple definition of `Matrix3D::~Matrix3D()'; main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xbea): first defined here
```

I have

```
#ifndef
#define

#endif
```

in all the hpp files, so I can't say why it's complaining about multiple definitions.

Separating out the -c and -o into their own things,

```
$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $@ $^

$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

, which was no different from removing the -c.

Removing -o, so it looks like:

```
$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $@ $^
```

, which makes it complain that Raytracer doesn't exist as a file or directory. (think I know why)

Placing out

```
%.o: %.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

, which makes nothing change, so I can't seem to understand how to make that work. And I can't find anything that helps me understand how to make it work.

Writing out the individual compilation steps above or below the $(NAME): $(OBJECTS) thing, for example

```
main.o: main.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $@ $<
```

, which just makes it tell me that there's "No rule to make target 'main.cc', needed by 'main.o'.  Stop.".

Placing out

```
$(OBJECTS): %.o: %.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $@ $<
```

, which also doesn't seem to do anything.

Changing $^ into $<, which does nothing for me other than reduce the amount of "linking not done" messages I recieve.

The Makefile:

```
DEBUG=false
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -std=c18
NAME=Raytracer
OBJECTS=main.o OBB.o Plane.o Ray.o Shape.o Sphere.o Triangle.o
RM=rm -f

ifeq    ($(DEBUG),true)
    CFLAGS += -g
else
    CFLAGS += -O2
endif

default: all

all: $(NAME)

$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) *.o $(NAME) $(OBJECTS)
```

Edit: ok, it was literally just -c that was the issue and it's my code that needs debugging now.

The Vector3D header:

```
#ifndef VECTOR3D_HPP
#define VECTOR3D_HPP

#include <cmath>

class Vector3D
{
    private:
        float x, y, z;
    public:
        Vector3D();
        Vector3D(float xCoord, float yCoord, float zCoord);
        
        float getX() const;
        float getY() const;
        float getZ() const;
    
        float operator*(Vector3D v2) const;
        Vector3D operator%(Vector3D v2) const;
        Vector3D operator+(Vector3D v2) const;
        Vector3D operator-(const Vector3D v2) const;
        Vector3D operator*(float mult) const;
        Vector3D operator/(float div) const;
        float Magnitude();
        Vector3D Normal();
        float& Matrixed();
        
        ~Vector3D();
};

Vector3D::Vector3D() {x=0.0f, y=0.0f, z=0.0f;}
Vector3D::Vector3D(float xCoord, float yCoord, float zCoord) {x=xCoord, y=yCoord, z=zCoord;}

float Vector3D::getX() const {return x;}
float Vector3D::getY() const {return y;}
float Vector3D::getZ() const {return z;}

float Vector3D::operator*(Vector3D v2) const {return x*v2.x + y*v2.y + z*v2.z;}

Vector3D Vector3D::operator%(Vector3D v2) const
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = y*v2.z - z*v2.y;
    res.y = z*v2.x - x*v2.z;
    res.z = x*v2.y - y*v2.x;
    return res;
}

Vector3D Vector3D::operator+(Vector3D v2) const
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = x + v2.x;
    res.y = y + v2.y;
    res.z = z + v2.z;
    return res;
}

Vector3D Vector3D::operator-(Vector3D v2) const
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = x - v2.x;
    res.y = y - v2.y;
    res.z = z - v2.z;
    return res;
}

Vector3D Vector3D::operator*(float mult) const
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = x*mult;
    res.y = y*mult;
    res.z = z*mult;
    return res;
}

Vector3D Vector3D::operator/(float div) const
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = x/div;
    res.y = y/div;
    res.z = z/div;
    return res;
}

float Vector3D::Magnitude() {return sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);}

Vector3D Vector3D::Normal()
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = x/sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    res.y = y/sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    res.z = z/sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    return res;
}

float& Vector3D::Matrixed()
{
    float list[3] ={getX(), getY(), getZ()};
    float& ref = *list;
    return ref;
}

Vector3D::~Vector3D(){}

#endif
```

What I took out from the hpp and put inside the Vector3D file:

```
Vector3D::Vector3D() {x=0.0f, y=0.0f, z=0.0f;}
Vector3D::Vector3D(float xCoord, float yCoord, float zCoord) {x=xCoord, y=yCoord, z=zCoord;}

float Vector3D::getX() const {return x;}
float Vector3D::getY() const {return y;}
float Vector3D::getZ() const {return z;}

float Vector3D::operator*(Vector3D v2) const {return x*v2.x + y*v2.y + z*v2.z;}

Vector3D Vector3D::operator%(Vector3D v2) const
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = y*v2.z - z*v2.y;
    res.y = z*v2.x - x*v2.z;
    res.z = x*v2.y - y*v2.x;
    return res;
}

Vector3D Vector3D::operator+(Vector3D v2) const
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = x + v2.x;
    res.y = y + v2.y;
    res.z = z + v2.z;
    return res;
}

Vector3D Vector3D::operator-(Vector3D v2) const
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = x - v2.x;
    res.y = y - v2.y;
    res.z = z - v2.z;
    return res;
}

Vector3D Vector3D::operator*(float mult) const
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = x*mult;
    res.y = y*mult;
    res.z = z*mult;
    return res;
}

Vector3D Vector3D::operator/(float div) const
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = x/div;
    res.y = y/div;
    res.z = z/div;
    return res;
}

float Vector3D::Magnitude() {return sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);}

Vector3D Vector3D::Normal()
{
    Vector3D res;
    res.x = x/sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    res.y = y/sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    res.z = z/sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    return res;
}

float& Vector3D::Matrixed()
{
    float list[3] ={getX(), getY(), getZ()};
    float& ref = *list;
    return ref;
}

Vector3D::~Vector3D(){}
```

The Matrix3D header:

```
#ifndef MATRIX3D_HPP
#define MATRIX3D_HPP

#include "3DVector.hpp"

class Matrix3D
{
    private:

    public:
                  //[Row][Col]
        float elements[3][3];
        Matrix3D();
        Matrix3D(Vector3D u, Vector3D v, Vector3D w);
        Matrix3D(float xx, float yx, float zx,
                 float xy, float yy, float zy,
                 float xz, float yz, float zz);
        Matrix3D operator*(Matrix3D m2);

        Matrix3D rotateX(float phi);
        Matrix3D rotateY(float theta);
        Matrix3D rotateZ(float psi);
        ~Matrix3D();
};

Matrix3D::Matrix3D(){float elements[3][3] = {{1.0f,0.0f,0.0f}, {0.0f,1.0f,0.0f}, {0.0f,0.0f,1.0f}};}
Matrix3D::Matrix3D(Vector3D u, Vector3D v, Vector3D w) {float elements[3][3] = {v.Matrixed(), u.Matrixed(), w.Matrixed()};}
Matrix3D::Matrix3D(float xx, float yx, float zx,
                 float xy, float yy, float zy,
                 float xz, float yz, float zz)
{
    float elements[3][3] = {xx, yx, zx,
                            xy, yy, zy,
                            xz, yz, zz};
}

Matrix3D Matrix3D::operator*(Matrix3D m2)
{
    Matrix3D result;
    for(short j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        for(short k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            float sum = 0.0f;
            for(short i = 0; i < 3; i++) sum += elements[j][i] * m2.elements[i][k];
            result.elements[j][k] = sum;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Matrix3D Matrix3D::rotateX(float phi)
{
    const float sinPhi = sin(phi);
    const float cosPhi = cos(phi);
    return
    {
        1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f,
        0.0f, cosPhi, sinPhi,
        0.0f,-sinPhi, cosPhi
    };
}
Matrix3D Matrix3D::rotateY(float theta)
{
    const float sinTheta = sin(theta);
    const float cosTheta = cos(theta);
    return
    {
         cosTheta, 0.0f,-sinTheta,
         0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
         sinTheta, 0.0f, cosTheta
    };
}
Matrix3D Matrix3D::rotateZ(float psi)
{
    const float sinPsi = sin(psi);
    const float cosPsi = cos(psi);
    return
    {
        cosPsi,  sinPsi, 0.0f,
        -sinPsi, cosPsi, 0.0f,
        0.0f,    0.0f,   1.0f
    };
}

Matrix3D::~Matrix3D(){}

Vector3D operator*(const Vector3D& v, const Matrix3D& m)
{
    return
    {
        v.getX() * m.elements[0][0] + v.getY() * m.elements[1][0] + v.getZ() * m.elements[2][0],
        v.getX() * m.elements[0][1] + v.getY() * m.elements[1][1] + v.getZ() * m.elements[2][1],
        v.getX() * m.elements[0][2] + v.getY() * m.elements[1][2] + v.getZ() * m.elements[2][2]
    };
}

#endif
```

What I took out from the hpp and put inside the Matrix3D file:

```
Matrix3D::Matrix3D(){float elements[3][3] = {{1.0f,0.0f,0.0f}, {0.0f,1.0f,0.0f}, {0.0f,0.0f,1.0f}};}
Matrix3D::Matrix3D(Vector3D u, Vector3D v, Vector3D w) {float elements[3][3] = {v.Matrixed(), u.Matrixed(), w.Matrixed()};}
Matrix3D::Matrix3D(float xx, float yx, float zx,
                 float xy, float yy, float zy,
                 float xz, float yz, float zz)
{
    float elements[3][3] = {xx, yx, zx,
                            xy, yy, zy,
                            xz, yz, zz};
}

Matrix3D Matrix3D::operator*(Matrix3D m2)
{
    Matrix3D result;
    for(short j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        for(short k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        {
            float sum = 0.0f;
            for(short i = 0; i < 3; i++) sum += elements[j][i] * m2.elements[i][k];
            result.elements[j][k] = sum;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

Matrix3D Matrix3D::rotateX(float phi)
{
    const float sinPhi = sin(phi);
    const float cosPhi = cos(phi);
    return
    {
        1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f,
        0.0f, cosPhi, sinPhi,
        0.0f,-sinPhi, cosPhi
    };
}
Matrix3D Matrix3D::rotateY(float theta)
{
    const float sinTheta = sin(theta);
    const float cosTheta = cos(theta);
    return
    {
         cosTheta, 0.0f,-sinTheta,
         0.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f,
         sinTheta, 0.0f, cosTheta
    };
}
Matrix3D Matrix3D::rotateZ(float psi)
{
    const float sinPsi = sin(psi);
    const float cosPsi = cos(psi);
    return
    {
        cosPsi,  sinPsi, 0.0f,
        -sinPsi, cosPsi, 0.0f,
        0.0f,    0.0f,   1.0f
    };
}

Matrix3D::~Matrix3D(){}
```

Edit: I now have to go through my code to see what I'm doing wrong because I'm getting a lot fewer cygwin errors with $<, but now they're along the lines of:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: 3DMatrix.o:3DMatrix.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `Vector3D::getX() const'
3DMatrix.o:3DMatrix.cpp:(.text+0x29): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Vector3D::getX() const'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: 3DMatrix.o:3DMatrix.cpp:(.text+0x225): undefined reference to `Vector3D::Matrixed()'
3DMatrix.o:3DMatrix.cpp:(.text+0x225): additional relocation overflows omitted from the output
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../lib/libcygwin.a(libcmain.o): in function `main':
/usr/src/debug/cygwin-3.1.7-1/winsup/cygwin/lib/libcmain.c:37: undefined reference to `WinMain'
```

Though that changes back to the regular multiple definition error if I use $^ in the header file, so I think the way forward is to use $<. Though then again, there's also a bunch of new stuff in the cygwin errors for $^ such as

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa03): undefined reference to `stbi_write_png'
main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0xa03): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `stbi_write_png'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: main.o:main.cpp:(.xdata+0x28): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_seh0'
main.o:main.cpp:(.xdata+0x28): relocation truncated to fit: rva32 against undefined symbol `__gxx_personality_seh0'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: main.o:main.cpp:(.text$_ZNSt20__uninitialized_copyILb0EE13__uninit_copyISt13move_iteratorIPSt10unique_ptrI5ShapeSt14default_deleteIS4_EEES8_EET0_T_SB_SA_[_ZNSt20__uninitialized_copyILb0EE13__uninit_copyISt13move_iteratorIPSt10unique_ptrI5ShapeSt14default_deleteIS4_EEES8_EET0_T_SB_SA_]+0x90): undefined reference to `__cxa_end_catch'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/10/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: OBB.o:OBB.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTI3OBB[_ZTI3OBB]+0x0): undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info'
```

Comment: You seem to be approaching the problem by trying out a bunch of variations on your makefile without really understanding what they mean (else you would know which are appropriate and which not).  Allow me to suggest that a better way forward is to learn what the syntax you're using means and what the messages you are receiving mean -- then you will be better equipped to determine what to do.

Comment: Please don't edit your post in a way that completely changes the nature of the Question. More generally, you seem to be getting this rat's nest of errors because you wrote a lot of code before testing any of it. You'll have a much easier time if you start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step. That way the errors will appear one or two at a time, and you'll know exactly where to look for the causes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $^
```

with

```
$(NAME): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^
```

The `-c` option is wrong (and is what is preventing linking).

You say that removing `-c` gives a bunch of cygwin errors. Could you share those errors? Just because you get more errors doesn't mean that removing `-c` is the wrong thing to do.

**UPDATE**

Well the error list proves that linking is now happening, which is progress. Unfortunately the new errors are caused by problems in your code. Since I can't see the code I can't really tell you how to fix them.

Putting non-inlined function definitions in header files would be one way to cause that kind of error. So would using `#include` on source files. Other possibilities exist as well.

**MORE UPDATES**

> I have
>
> #ifndef
> #define
>
> #endif
>
> in all the hpp files, so I can't say why it's complaining about
> multiple definitions.

This is a common miunderstanding. Include guards are not a cure for multiple definition errors.

Look at your header files, do they contain non-inlined function definitions? If so then fix that, either by making the function definition inline, or by moving the function definition out of the header file.

**UPDATE UPDATE**

Exactly as I said, your header files are stuffed full of non-inlined function definitions. Fix them.

And to repeat, include guards have nothing at all to do with this issue.

Comment: Sometimes doing the right thing allows the build to get further and find more errors. I remember the good old days when I'd celebrate winnowing the errors down to a mere missing semicolon, add the semicolon, and be rewarded with hundreds of new compiler errors.

Comment: Indeed.  That removing the inappropriate `-c` option -- whose purpose is specifically to prevent linking -- leads to a bunch of errors is in this case a sign that it is the *right* thing to do.  One can come to that possibly-surprising conclusion by observing that all the new errors are emitted *by the linker*.